# error during array creation in bash

Tags: bash

I have a couple of files with certain keywors (one is MAT1).
For this key word i like to read the ID corresponding to it, put this together with the filename into an array.
I tried the following (I am not very familiar with bash programming):

```
#!/bin/bash
Num=0
arr=( $(find . -name '*.mat' | sort) )

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do

  file=$(basename "${i}")

  while read -r line
  do

  name="$line"
  IFS=' ' read -r -a array <<< "$line"
    for index in "${!array[@]}"
    do

      if [ ${array[index]} == "MAT1" ]
      then
        out[$num] = "${array[index+1]} $file "
        let num++
        #printf "%-32s %8i\n" "$file" "${array[index+1]}"
      fi

    done

  done < "$i"

done
```

With this get the message

make_mat_list.bsh: line 21: out[0]: command not found

make_mat_list.bsh: line 21: out[1]: command not found

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bash` is white-space sensitive, your line below cannot have spaces.

```
out[$num] = "${array[index+1]} $file "
```

As for the reason for the error, the shell treats that particular line as the first word being a command `out[$num]` i.e. `out[1]`..etc and rest of it as arguments to it `=` and  `"${array[index+1]} $file "`, which does not make any sense. Remove the spaces and do jsut

```
out[$num]="${array[index+1]} $file"
```